# jQuery - how to put html elements on page using javascript

Tags: jquery, html

I am a jQuery newbie. I am trying to do something like this:

```
function putJStorageValues () { 
  var keys = getJStorageValues();
  var test = "";
  jQuery.each(keys, function(index, item) {
    test += "<br>" + item;
  });
  $("#storageValues").text(test);
}
```

But this ends up with "
 myItem". How would I print HTML such that there is a line break and then the item?

Comment: Don't forget in a question to say where exactly the problem is. At the moment there is no question here. Just you telling us what you are doing! :) I was almost tempted to answer with "And how's that going?" :)

Comment: @Chris edited it for your benefit :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$("#storageValues").text(test);` <-- this puts text on an element (strips HTML)
`$("#storageValues").html(test);` <-- this puts HTML in an element

Answer (score 2):

You better use .html method as you have `<br/>` in text or you might expect other html elements  in the text.

```
$("#storageValues").html(test);
```

.html() - This jQuery function gets/sets the HTML of any element.
.text()- This jQuery function gets/sets the text (innertext) of any element. [`Details`](http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2011/02/difference-between-jquery-text-and-html.html)

```
function putJStorageValues () {

var keys = getJStorageValues();
var test = "";
jQuery.each(keys, function(index, item) {
    test += "<br>" + item;
});
$("#storageValues").html(test);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

```
function putJStorageValues () {

     var keys = getJStorageValues();
     var test = "";
     jQuery.each(keys, function(index, item) {
          test += "<br>" + item;
     });

     $("#storageValues").append(test);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually DOM manipulation is done with the `appendChild` function, or `append` in jQuery. This requires the *creation* of DOM elements to append.

```
function putJStorageValues () {

 var keys = getJStorageValues();
 jQuery.each(keys, function(index, item) {
  var toInsert = document.createElement("p");
  p.innerHTML = item;
  $("#storageValues").append(toInsert);
 });
}
```